What kind of comma is at play in this sentence from Middlemarch?
I had what I esteem was a really basic education in English grammar, so I’m a bit puzzled about the comma before ”that Will Ladislaw” in this sentence from George Eliot’s Middlemarch:

Perhaps, through all other hidden thoughts, the one that breathed most comfort was, that Will Ladislaw at least was not likely to publish what had taken place that evening.

After some basic research, the explanation I’ve considered is that commas before restrictive clauses used to be more common in written English back when the book was published. I’ve also observed commas before “that” in Polish grammar when I dabbled in it, but in English texts it seems a bit odd.
Would anyone here have a more confident answer?

I read the comma after 'was' as a marker for an omitted term: 'this:'. That is, I think that instead of saying, 'Perhaps, through all other hidden thoughts, the one that breathed most comfort was this: that Will Ladislaw at least was not likely to publish what had taken place that evening,' Eliot decided to put a comma after 'was' and drop the 'this:'. If that's what happened, her punctuation decision certainly qualifies as idiosyncratic—but the same could be said of a lot of decisions that writers make about comma use, even today.

I’d call this a comma of the Victorian Era. And I wouldn’t worry any further about it. Nowadays, we would not find a comma before a that-clause: ...[the thought] that breathed most comfort was that Will Ladislaw was not likely to publish...

It's not a grammatical comma at all - instead, it's an 'intonation cues for the reader'-type comma. Think of it like stage directions for the person reading the book out loud: the author wants to indicate to them that they should pause after the word "was," for effect. It gives the listener time to "catch up" (as it's a fairly long sentence), and helps to focus the attention on what comes next (the "that" clause). It's because it's just being used as a cue for reading out loud, that you haven't been able to find a grammar rule prescribing it.

I don't have any kind of authoritative source to cite for this type of usage (hopefully someone else here will!) so that's why I posted that as a comment instead of an answer. But, I'm very familiar with that kind of "stylistic pause" from listening to audiobooks. Since current writing style is more prescriptive about punctuation, the narrators are likely having to figure out stuff like this without the benefit of such clues. But, back when punctuation usage wasn't as standardized, I believe it wasn't uncommon for it to be used in this way.

Some would say that the inclusion of this comma is just plain wrong, at least  nowadays. I'd say that the real problem is an over-long, unwieldy sentence, with a comma inserted into a non-standard slot in an attempt to make the sentence more decipherable. << A welter of secret thoughts seethed through his mind. Perhaps the one that breathed most comfort was that Will Ladislaw (at least) was not likely to publish what had taken place that evening. >> Though I don't see how 'at least' fits here: were others likely to publish? Or does 'publish' mean 'divulge' here?

I appreciate the input, folks. I think calling it a “prosodic comma” will do it for me.


...  that Will Ladislaw at least was not likely to publish what had taken place that evening.

The above is not a "restrictive clause" but a clause with nominal, noun-like, force, a content-clause, the predicate complement of "the one [thought] that breathed most comfort restrictive was,  [that Will Ladislaw at least was not likely to publish what had taken place that evening].content clause
The sentence could be rewritten

That Will Ladislaw at least was not likely to publish what had taken place that evening was, perhaps, the one  thought through all other hidden thoughts that breathed most comfort.

A pause after was isolates the content-clause. I think the isolation reinforces the nominal role of the clause.
Nowadays we often hear copula was "attached" to the front of the complement:

The one thing that most puzzled me of all the events of that evening, was that they took so long to call the police.

A pause before "was" and "was that" spoken in rapid succession.  At least that's the prosody in the American English  I hear every day.

Much like the other comments, I think your answer reaches a satisfying conclusion with a similar point: it’s sort of a prosodic comma inserted for intonation. And thank you for the insight on the role of that clause

@BartholomewCubbins  When you answer on this forum, you expose yourself to anonymous downvotes, whereas comments are immune to that.

@BartholomewCubbins I'd say that the prosody plays a syntax-clarifying role. It's not "intontation for intonation's sake", as it were, to add some rhythm, or a mere "rhetorical pause for emphasis".

I see. Also, for what it’s worth, I tried upvoting your answer, but it seems I can’t as a newcomer.

@BartholomewCubbins Thanks :-)  That's OK.   I'm even happy to have downvotes if the downvoter explains why they have taken issue with something I've said. It may indicate that I've not explained my point clearly enough.
